# Function to check for duplicates based on condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a simple Google sheet that records what sessions people are signed up for (3 concurrent sessions per day):

[image: duplicates]

The same person cannot be in more than 1 session on a given day. I'd like to create a function in column B that checks for that situation and flags it, as in Susan, Keith, and Amy in the example above (I've highlighted in yellow the conditions that would trigger a flag).

If there were just one date, I'd use a countif (or maybe countifs?) to check for more than 1 TRUE for that date. But with multiple dates, I think some sort of iterative function or query is needed. I have a feeling I may be missing a simple formula, but it's eluding me. I may add more dates, so the solution needs to allow for n number of dates in the range.

**UPDATE:** My scenario has become a little more complex. I'm designating a potential role each person can play in each session and then using the checkboxes to indicate who is playing what role in each session. A given person can't be in more than 1 session per day (but a given person may be in 0 sessions on a given day). The below image shows this updated scenario, with the yellow highlights showing the conditions that I want flagged via the function in column B.

[image: Updated Scenario]

Here's a [link to the Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AlB20jiu5xKkRAht-1N-5i9RlFqsmJOQ-w2sREVdlu8/copy) if you want to create a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Given the use case provided, you can apply the formula below to B3 and drag the auto-complete handle:

`=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INT(C3:K3))) = COUNTUNIQUE($C$1:$1), "", "FLAG")`

I'm converting the Boolean values to INT and summing them up. If the sum is equal to the count of unique days in the first row, then everything is fine, otherwise, FLAG!
In other words, if there are more (or less) checks than days, it should be flagged.

You can also set up a conditional formatting to paint the cell accordingly.

Alternatively, if you’d like to treat each scenario you can use `=IFS()` as below:

`=IFS(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INT(C3:K3))) > COUNTUNIQUE($C$1:$1), "HIGHER", ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INT(C3:K3))) < COUNTUNIQUE($C$1:$1), "LOWER", ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INT(C3:K3))) = COUNTUNIQUE($C$1:$1), "OK")`

#### References:

- [Sheets Functions documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273)
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)
- [INT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093490)
- [COUNTUNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093405)

### EDIT:

- Since the changes in the original scope significantly impacted my previous answer, here is a suggestion using a custom formula:

```js
function checkFlags(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // get active Sheets
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // getting tab named "Sheet1"
  var currentCellRange = ss.getActiveRange(); // getting active cell, in the context of a custom formula, it gets the one being calculated at the time
  var rowIndex = currentCellRange.getRowIndex(); //getting current row number 

  var rowValues = ws.getRange(`${rowIndex}:${rowIndex}`).getValues()[0]; //getting row cells values
  
  var sessionsList = []; //temp variable to store useful data from cells

  for (var i = 0; i < rowValues.length; i++) { //reading cells on the row to create a date/flag array
    var cell = rowValues[i]; //getting Range of current cell
    if (typeof(cell) == 'boolean'){ //if the current cell has a boolean value, it is a session flag
      var headerDate = ws.getRange(2, (i+2)).getDisplayValue(); //getting the header value on row 2 (current date for the session flag)
      sessionsList.push({date: headerDate, session: cell});//storing date and session flag value on the temp variable
    }
  };

  var groupBy = function(xs, key) { //handle function to proccess the sessionsList variable and group flag values by 'date'
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
      (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
      return rv;
    }, {});
  };

  var tempGroupedArray = groupBy(sessionsList, 'date'); //grouping temp sessionsList by 'date'. This will return an array like [ { date: '<date>', session: true/false }, { date: '<date>', session: true/false }, ...]

  for (dateFlags of Object.entries(tempGroupedArray)) {//looping through the `grouped by date` array 
    var tempCount = dateFlags[1].filter(x => x.session==true).length; //how many `trues` are for this date
    if (tempCount > 1){ //if there is more than one session set as "true" for this date...
      return 'FLAG'; //...immediately stop execution and return FLAG
    }
  };
  //if it passed the loop above, it means there is no flags
  return ''; //then return blank
}
```

- NOTES: This custom formula will not update the result in the cell after a change on the flag values, you must delete/paste it to force if wanted.

Comment: Thank you, @Gustavo. Your solution works like a charm on my original scenario! I've updated the post with a more complex scenario. In this scenario, I have non-boolean values in the table, which makes the integer conversion in your function no longer work. Would you be able to modify your function to account for this updated scenario?

Comment: @d-ron You can still use the same logic if you manually declare the checkboxes cells as the INT conversion input. However what breaks my last implementation logic is the fact that a person may not have a session for a given day. That means that in case a user did not have a session active for a day but 2 active sessions in the next day, my previous solution will not flag it. I cannot think of a simple way to do that with built-in functions. Are you comfortable using Apps Scripts?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm a relative newbie with app script, but I've been learning. I was decent with Excel VBA and have had to learn app script from scratch. If there's a solution using app script, I'm open to it!

Comment: Hi @d-ron, I've edited with a suggestion of a custom formula that might work for you.